# Palindrome checking function

Tags: php, strings, palindrome

I recently did a little task for fun that required me to create a class to determine if a word is a palindrome or not. I know this is quite simple, but I'd be interested to know if a real developer (I'm not a programmer) would approach the task in the same way, or if I make any amateur mistakes/do anything stupid.

My code passed the automated tests on the website, but I understand those aren't perfect.

```
class Palindrome
{
    public static function isPalindrome($word)
    {
        $word = strtolower($word);
        $wordLength = strlen($word);
        $wordSplitPoint = ceil($wordLength / 2);

        if ($wordLength % 2 == 0) {
            $firstHalf = substr($word, 0, $wordSplitPoint);
            $secondHalf = substr($word, $wordSplitPoint, $wordSplitPoint);
        } else {
            $firstHalf = substr($word, 0, $wordSplitPoint-1);
            $secondHalf = substr($word, $wordSplitPoint, $wordSplitPoint);
        }

        $secondHalfReversed = strrev($secondHalf);

        if ($firstHalf == $secondHalfReversed) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

echo Palindrome::isPalindrome('Deleveled');
```

Comment: Perhaps this is "outside" of the question/problem, but: Why is it in a class? Why not just make a standalone function? I don't know PHP, but to my understanding, it doesn't mandate top-level classes like Java does.

Comment: @Quelklef The task specifically asks for it to be in a class and only allows you to modify what is contained within the `isPalindrome` function

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Others have pointed out a fix you could make to your implementation.  But there is a way to write this which is much simpler.  That takes advantage of a simplified definition of palindrome: "a word which reads the same forwards and backwards".

Now I haven't done PHP in years, and don't have a test environment, so this might have issues, but the basic idea should be clear.

```
public static function isPalindrome($word)
{
    return $word == strrev($word);
}
```

---

### Update

Based on suggestions in the comments, this would be nicer:

```
function isPalindrome($word) {
    $word = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $word);
    $word = strtolower($word);
    return $word == strrev($word);
}
```

That will now correctly identify "Level" (ignoring capitalization) and "Madam, I'm Adam." (ignoring spaces and punctuation.)

Comment: Smart :) I like it!

Comment: And what is the reason of the divorce?

Comment: You should make $word lowercase before you do the return. Else  "Level" will not be valid as a palindrome.

Comment: this is exactly what i was thinking :) I agree with Tonny, but would also add something to strip white spaces so that "taco cat" evaluates as true

Comment: Yes, both the lowercase and the space removal would be useful.  But my PHP days are long ago and far away!

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: I never did much with it.  But I absolutely prefer functional languages: ML, Haskell, OCaml, Erlang, various LISPs, and usually program by day in JavaScript.

Comment: Updated with the suggestions incorporated.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very good program. There is only one thing I'd change:

> ```
> if ($firstHalf == $secondHalfReversed) {
>     return TRUE;
> } else {
>     return FALSE;
> }
> ```

You don't really need that if because the top part only returns `TRUE` when the condition also is `TRUE`. Otherwise, both the condition and the return is `FALSE`. Change it to:

```
return $firstHalf == $secondHalfReversed
```

Answer (score 8):

To start with id remove the code that you written twice by re-arranging the if statement into this

```
if ($wordLength % 2 == 0) {
    $firstHalf = substr($word, 0, $wordSplitPoint);
} else {
    $firstHalf = substr($word, 0, $wordSplitPoint-1);
}

$secondHalf = substr($word, $wordSplitPoint, $wordSplitPoint);
```

Then for the return value I would use;

```
return $firstHalf == $secondHalfReversed;
```

This is about all i would change

Comment: Thanks, no reason why the `$secondHalf` should be repeated, and that return is much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I'd write this using a traditional for loop as follows:

```
class Palindrome
{
    public static function isPalindrome($word)
    {
      $wordLength = strlen($word)-1;

      for ($i = 0; $i < $wordLength/2; $i++) {
        if (strtolower($word[$i]) != strtolower($word[$wordLength-$i])) {
          return FALSE;
        }
      }

      return TRUE;
    }
}

echo Palindrome::isPalindrome('Deleveled');
```

Comment: Pedantically, this approach would be less computing power than the other approaches.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Answer (score 1):

```
echo Palindrome::isPalindrome('Deleveled');
```

You need to test corner cases and try to break your code. For example, you might try with:

- a string of odd size
- a string of even size
- the empty string
- a string with one character

How is size defined anyway? What about encodings? For example, your code works for '101', but not 'é_é'?

Comment: The task I completed on the website wanted a function that could detect single-word palindromes of varying lengths. But you're right. Edge cases are something I need to consider more. I'm trying hard to leave the world of "duck-tape" php behind. "It only broke because you aren't using it correctly" is a terrible philosophy :)